# jQuery getting value of updated select input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I update the value of a select input like so:

```
$('.filter').change(function() {

        $.post('/schedules', { sid: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(k, v) {
                var least = 0;

                if(v.sort_c > least) {
                    $('.filter2').append('<option value="' + v.id + '.' + 'test_value' + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
                    least = v.sort_c;
                }
            });
        });
});
```

After this jQuery runs I need to then get the value of `$('.filter2')`.  When I try to do `$('.filter2').val()` it returns nothing.

Why is this happening?

Comment: did you check what is the actual value assigned to the selected `option`?

Comment: i tried it.. works fine. please inspect element and check if value are assigned to options

Comment: When you say ***After this jQuery runs** what, exactly, do you mean? Have you taken into account the fact that there is an asynchronous request involved?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to find the value of the selected option inside your select named `filter2`. Try this:

```
$('.filter2 option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

***After this jQuery runs*** seems to imply that you're not taking into account the *asynchronous*(AJAX) request involved. The following should give you the correct value of `.filter2`:

```
$('.filter').change(function() {

        $.post('/schedules', { sid: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(k, v) {
                var least = 0;

                if(v.sort_c > least) {
                    $('.filter2').append('<option value="' + v.id + '.' + 'test_value' + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
                    least = v.sort_c;
                }
            });
            console.log( $('.filter2').val() ); //<========
        });
});
```

However, since I don't see you setting any of the *new* options with a `selected` attribute, I wonder what value you expect to get that you would not get before the change.